# Can a has_many through association be polymorphic?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have a Ship model that has_many pilots. A pilot can be either a Character or a Faction. Can I use a has_many :through association to model this?

```
class Ship < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pilots, :through => :pilot_assignments, :polymorphic => true
  has_many :pilot_assignments
end

class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ships, :through => :pilot_assignments
  has_many :pilot_assignments
end

class Faction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ships, :through => :pilot_assignments
  has_many :pilot_assignments
end

class PilotAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ship
  belongs_to :pilot, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Comment: what about my answer? does it works? did you find answer on your question?

Comment: Yes, it worked nicely enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something like:

```
class PilotAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ship
  belongs_to :pilot, polymorphic: true
end

class Ship < ActiveRecord::Base
  # i'm not sure should be there some additional options or not (like as: :pilot)
  has_many :pilots, through: :pilot_assignments
  has_many :pilot_assignments
end

class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ships, through: :pilot_assignments
  has_many :pilot_assignments, as: :pilot
end

class Faction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ships, through: :pilot_assignments
  has_many :pilot_assignments, as: :pilot
end
```

also `PilotAssignment` should contain: `pilot_type`, `pilot_id`